# How to compare a file w.r.t a keyword file and replace mismatch strings of column 3 with correct string in column 3 of keyword file

Tags: linux, shell, perl, awk, sed

I want to search every line of **search_file** in **keyword_file** and print an **output_file** replacing the incorrect string of the line with the correct string extracted from **keyword_file**. Also, should warn the user if there are few entries with missing 3rd column, which do not exist in **keyword_file** and have  in **search_file** (for example, "ggg coms" in the file)

Note, here **keyword_file** may contain an unequal number of line compared to **search_file**. For example:
**search_file**

```
aaa coms 123
bbb coms 234
ccc 
ddd coms 456
eez coms 789
fkk coms 987
ggg coms   
hhh coms 989
....
```

**keyword_file**

```
aaa coms 789
bbb coms 234
ccc coms 878
ddd coms 456
ttt coms 654 
eee coms 789
```

**Output**

```
aaa coms 789
bbb coms 234
ccc coms 878
ddd coms 456
eez coms 789
fkk coms 987
hhh coms 989
....
```

I tried the following awk command, but it was not able to retain column #1 entries of **search_file** in the **Output**.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0} FNR!=NR&&a[$1]{print $1,$2,$3}' search_file keyword_file
```

Thank you in advanced for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested based on shown samples only.

```
awk '
{
  key=$1
}
FNR==NR{
  a[key]=$3
  next
}
(key in a){
  $0=key OFS $2 OFS a[key]
}
1
'  keyword_file  search_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  key=$1                             ##Run this command on each line of Input_file and create variable key with value of 1st field.
}
FNR==NR{                             ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when keyword_file is being read.
  a[key]=$3                          ##Creating array a with index key and value of 3rd field here.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
(key in a){                          ##Checking condition if key is present in array a then do following.
  $0=key OFS $2 OFS a[key]           ##Setting value of key OFS 2nd field OFS array a value with index key here.
}
1                                    ##1 will print edited/non-edited values for all lines.
'  keyword_file  search_file         ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***Why OP's code didn't work:*** You were close you only printed lines where first and second fields are common in both the Input_files so what I did is: while checking condition if fields are common in both Input_files then re-create the line with new last value and then by mentioning `1` printing the current(edited/non-edited) lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your solution. It works as you mentioned. I updated my question to correctly match my scenario. With your solution, I'm unable to get "ccc" information. Can you please help me with thhat?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Accepted the answer!

Just a small issue, I'm not able to get "ccc coms 878" instead I get "ccc 878" is there any way we can get that?

Comment: @coolcom, well with your shown samples I am seeing `ccc coms 878` not sure why its not working for you, it worked fine for me.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, Does it depend on linux version I have? because I'm not able to get "ccc coms 878". Which part of the code is handling this, can you please guide me here. I'm a newbie to Linux.

Comment: @coolcom,sure you could check from your side, added explanation for your guidance cheers.